# PowerShell ISE not recognizing $profile variables

Tags: powershell, scripting, environment-variables, powershell-5.0

In my **$profile** directory, I have a few custom variables, as well as the default variables, such as **$root** (*which equals "C:\"*), etc. One custom variable I have holds the filepath to my desktop, so I can easily reference the path, and also not have to create the variable every time I start up PS. If I attempt to resolve any variable value from the **$profile** path within **ISE**(*both the script pane and console*) it does not work. However, if I use the regular PS terminal, it works no problem. Any suggestions or explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell ISE uses a different host profile than a standard PowerShell session. The `$profile` variable actually displays the profile for the `CurrentUserCurrentHost` profile by default, but there are [four profile locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7#the-profile-files) stored in this variable. Each of these locations are [dot-sourced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) by default when you load PowerShell. You can see this by typing `$profile | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty` to see the total profiles configured:

- AllUsersAllHosts
- AllUsersCurrentHost
- CurrentUserAllHosts
- CurrentUserCurrentHost

---

Before we continue, let's talk about what a **PowerShell Host** really is. From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/writing-a-windows-powershell-host-application?view=powershell-7):

> The host application can define the runspace where commands are run, open sessions on a local or remote computer, and invoke the commands either synchronously or asynchronously based on the needs of the application.

So what this means is that a PowerShell Host implements a PowerShell session. This can be `powershell.exe` for a basic, standard host, but there could be any number of alternative applications or development tools that may implement their own PowerShell Host as well, for a number of reasons.

---

The `AllHosts` profile locations should remain standard regardless of your PowerShell host, but different PowerShell hosts will typically set their own `CurrentHost` profile locations for their host. For example, `powershell.exe` is its own PowerShell host, and will have its own host-specific profiles, named `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`. `PowerShell ISE` implements its own PowerShell host, and has different host-specific profiles named `Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1`.

If you want code in your profile to be host-agnostic, you should make sure to place your profile code in one of the `AllHosts` profiles. Host-specific code, such as things you only want to be available in the context of the ISE PowerShell host, or a VSCode PowerShell host, should go into that host-specific profile.

Comment: Thank you for the level of detail! Can confirm this is my issue.

Comment: IMO it's kind of weird that `$profile` is a `System.String`, with `NoteProperty` properties added to it. If you don't know about those `NoteProperty` properties on `$profile`, and you don't read the `about_Profiles` doc, you may never realize that there are multiple profile locations you can use in a PowerShell session.

Answer (score 1):

$profile is different in the ISE:

```
$profile
C:\Users\js\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

console:

```
$profile
C:\Users\js\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```